# How to style a link created from a magnet port?

Tags: jointjs

im trying to figure out how to style a link when connecting two elements using drag and drop between ports.

I understand that you can style a link using the link.attr like this:

```
link.attr({
line: { // selector for the visible <path> SVGElement
    stroke: 'orange' // SVG attribute and value
}
```

});

given that you manually create the link and add it to the graph. However the only option I found styling a magnet link is when creating the paper like this:

```
initializeScene(domNode) {
this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: domNode,
  model: this.graph,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  gridSize: 1,
  //define the style of magnet links
  defaultLink: new joint.shapes.standard.Link({
    attrs: {
      line: {
        stroke: "#4e4e4e"
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Is there a way of individually style the links from a magnet. For example if I want a link created from port A to be blue and link created from port B to be red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaultLink option of joint.dia.Paper can also be a function instead of plain object. The function is of the form function(cellView, magnet). This way, you can dynamically define your default link for when the user "drags" a magnet to create a new link. For example:

```
this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: domNode,
  model: this.graph,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  gridSize: 1,
  //define the style of magnet links
  defaultLink: function(cellView, magnet) {
    return new joint.shapes.standard.Link({
        attrs: {
          line: {
            stroke: V(magnet).attr('port-group') === "blue-ports" ? "blue" : "red"
          }
        }
    }
  })
});
```

Documentation to defaultLink option is here: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.2/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.options.defaultLink